# Why does давай(те) take different forms - давай + inf. or давай + future?

Tags: грамматика, tense

- **давай**(**те**) **пить** чай / let's have some tea
- **давай**(**те**) **сыграем** / let's play

I'm confused; they both mean 'let's', but why does one take an infinitive and the other a future form?

Answer (score 5):

You can think of *both* forms as '*future* tense':

> давайте (будем) пить чай

or

> давайте попьём чаю

The difference is that **imperfective** verbs take the auxiliary verb **будем** (**-ет**, **ут**) to form future tense (*будем + infinitive*). In this particular expression *будем* can be omitted without *any* change in sense: it's either way a suggestion for future action.

So, both Russian versions follow the same template with *future*.

Answer (score 3):

**Давайте пойдем, давайте сыграем, давайте сделаем, давайте купим, давайте скажем** - all those Perfect forms denote actions as such, which we propose to start, perform and finish.

**Давайте идти быстрее, давайте говорить громче, давайте пить чай** - these infinitive forms express processes.

**Давайте покупать чаще, давайте говорить друг другу комплименты, давайте понимать друг друга** - in these cases the actions are either repeated or not possible to be accomplished.

A good exercise for the third case is very famous among the Russian native speakers. :) Here you are. http://spoemdruzya.ru/pesni-iz-filma/klyuch-bez-prava-peredachi/1037-davajte-vosklitsat-davajte-govorit-drug-drugu-komplimenty.html 
Btw, a more regular action for the compliments is another, and that's **делать комплименты**. "Говорить комплименты" is not quite a current norm.

Comment: говорить комплименты is hardly an invention of Okujava since it occurs at least as early as [1838](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1823,cd_max:1841&lr=lang_ru) and [elsewhere](http://search1.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%E3%EE%E2%EE%F0%E8%EB%20%EA%EE%EC%EF%EB%E8%EC%E5%ED%F2%FB&p=1) in the XIX century

Answer (score 1):

You can use either form, the difference is whether an action is continuous or finite.

- давай(те) **пить** чай / let's have tea
- давай(те) **выпьем** чаю / let's have some tea
- давай(те) **играть** / let's play
- давай(те) **сыграем** / let's have a game